# LU decomposition by hand

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

Can someone show me a step by step solution to calculate the $LU$ decompisition of the following matrix:
$A =  \begin{bmatrix}
      5 & 5 & 10 \\
      2 & 8 & 6  \\
      3 & 6 & -9
      \end{bmatrix}$

I am getting the correct U by I am having difficult getting the correct L. 
[Here is the correct Answer](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/matrices-calculators/matrix-calculator.php?formId=2&val1=5:5:10%3a%3a%3a;2:8:6%3anull%3anull%3anull;3:6%3a-9%3anull%3anull%3anull;null%3anull%3anull%3anull%3anull%3anull;null%3anull%3anull%3anull%3anull%3anull;null%3anull%3anull%3anull%3anull%3anull&val2=6&val3=6&rb1=lu)

Answer (score 4):

$A =  \begin{pmatrix}
      5 & 5 & 10 \\
      2 & 8 & 6  \\
      3 & 6 & -9
      \end{pmatrix}$

First step (working on the first column):
a) Multiply the first row with $l_{21}= \frac{2}{5}$ and subtract it from row 2
b) Multiply the first row with $l_{31}= \frac{3}{5}$ and subtract it from row 2

This leads to
$U^{(1)} = \begin{pmatrix}
           5 & 5 & 10 \\
           0 & 6 & 2  \\
           0 & 3 & -15
           \end{pmatrix}$

Second step (working on the second column):
c) Multiply row 2 with $l_{32} = \frac{1}{2}$ and subtract it from row 3.  This gives

$U = U^{(2)} = \begin{pmatrix}
               5 & 5 & 10 \\
               0 & 6 & 2  \\
               0 & 0 & -16
               \end{pmatrix}$

And we have 
$L = \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     l_{21} & 1 & 0 \\
     l_{31} & l_{32} & 1
     \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     \frac{2}{5} & 1 & 0 \\
     \frac{3}{5} & \frac{1}{2} & 1
     \end{pmatrix}
$

So note that $l_{ij}$ was used to create a zero in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column by multiplying (in the $j$-th step) the $j$-th row with $l_{ij}$ and subtract the result from the $i$-th row.

Comment: Ok i got that but how did you get 2/5 , 3/5 and 1/2. I am getting 2,3,3 respectively.

Comment: The first row of A is (5 5 10).  The second row of A is (2 8 6).   Find a number alpha such that in the result of  "second row" - alpha * "first row" the first component is zero.  That requires 2 - alpha*5 = 0.

Comment: Sorry that was a dumb question, I totally understand now! you made it very clear in your first answer!

Comment: No Problem, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First you want to form $U$, i.e. find some $M$ such that $MA = U$. Now recall that $A = LU$, which means that $L = AU^{-1}=A(MA)^{-1}=AA^{-1}M^{-1}=M^{-1}$. 
So you now have computed both $L$ and $U$.